# Array is not assignable to type 'never[]'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

[image]Could use some help figuring out why the type here is `never` or `never[]`

```
const effects: EFFECT_TYPES[] = editState === EDITSTATES.EDIT ? currentEffects : draftEffects;
  const currentImageUrl = urlFromEffects({
    baseURL: imageUrl,
    effects,
  });
```

throws
`Type 'EFFECT_TYPES[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. Type 'EFFECT_TYPES' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)`

[image: typescript error underlined]

Comment: show code for `urlFromEffects`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript incorrectly inferred the type of `effects` to be `never`, the remedy being to define the type of `effects` manually:

```
export const urlFromEffects = ({ baseURL, effects = []}: {
  baseURL: string;
  effects?: EFFECT_TYPES[];
}) => {
  // ...
}
```